# How to dispose of solder waste?

Tags: soldering

Is there a safe way to dispose of lead solder waste?

Like used sponges, PCBs, tips, etc.

Should I place it in a bag, label it and throw it to a battery disposal boxes I see here and there?

Comment: This probably depends on your location, legislation and abilities to dispose stuff.

Comment: I live in a country that have very limited regulations with regards to recycling and I can't find anything with regard to small amounts of hazardous materials. Still, is there anything I can do? I'd rather not throw it to the garbage. @PlasmaHH

Comment: Lead solder or lead-free? If you're not involved in a business there may be a household hazardous waste depot you can drop it off at for free (for example, used for CFL lamps, paint, lead acid batteries etc.). How are you supposed to dispose of unwanted electronic products in your area?

Comment: Solder with lead, there's nothing to worry about with lead free no? I'm not involved with a business unfortunately. There's no regulations for disposing electronics, people just throw it in the garbage. @SpehroPefhany

Comment: +1 for using the same place as broken electronics go (for small amounts of solder). They contain also small amounts of solder.

Comment: @kuhaku: there are what, like 200 countries on this planet alone, we can not give advice that fits all.

Comment: @kuhaku Actually it's *fortunately* you're not involved with a business. Disposal is usually far more onerous for businesses which are presumed to have more resources and to be capable of footing the bill. Consumer waste is usually free to deal with (because otherwise people will just toss it).

Comment: @PlasmaHH well I hoped there's something an average Joe can do on his own.

Comment: @kuhaku: besides trying to figure out what the regulations for his country say where to dump it? Yeah, keep it until you know, or just throw it in the bin where no one will notice it anyways and wake up each night dreaming about how you destroyed the environment ^^

Comment: Since there are no regulations there, try to find out where various trash ends up. Ideally you want to keep it out of the ground (such as a landfill). And where people won't directly handle it without precautions. If everything goes into a landfill there is not much else you can do, other than not throwing it away.

Comment: Garbage... Lead comes from the environment, it is okay to put it back.

Comment: @HighInBC it comes from mines that aren't near our water source.

Comment: The trick is to not make your water source and your garbage dump the same place. Pro-tip: Throw the garbage into the lead mine!

Answer (score 2):

Do a web search on `recycle solder waste` and you'll find plenty of companies that will pay money for it (if you have enough) presumably they will accept small quantities from walk-in customers (and perhaps by mail).  circuitboards may be harder to dispose of as the substrate has negative monetary value